# How to add homebrew directory to PATH variable on MacOS?

Tags: r

I am trying to add my homebrew directory (that contains several command line tools I would like to use from within R) to my `PATH` variable in R. I am using RStudio on MacOS.

I opened the `.Renviron` file using `usethis::edit_r_environ()`, added the line `PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:${PATH}`, saved it and restarted the R session.  However, the directory does not show up under `Sys.getenv("PATH")`. Omitting the curly braces or adding quotation marks does not help either.

Do you spot an issue with my approach here?

Comment: What file did that give you?  What values are in your `R_ENVIRON` and `R_ENVIRON_USER` environment variables? The search order for `.Renviron.site` and  `.Renviron` is given in the `?Startup` help page.

Comment: Both `R_ENVIRON` and `R_ENVIRON_USER` return an empty string. So according to the `?Startup` help page, `.Renviron` should be used in that case? In `R_HOME/etc/` I do not have a file called `Renviron.site`, only `Renviron`, but removing that prevents R Studio from starting up at all.

Comment: The `Renviron` file belongs to R.  It shouldn't be changed.  You didn't answer my first question:  what file did you edit?

Comment: `usethis::edit_r_environ()` without any arguments seems to open `~/.Renviron`. That's the file that has been edited.

Comment: That's the right file to edit.  If you add another environment variable to that file, does it appear within R?  Something else might be messing with PATH.

Comment: Good point - I had `R_MAX_VSIZE=100Gb` set as well but just noticed that that doesn't get picked up either. Interestingly, the problem seems to be specific to R Studio. Everything works fine when I use the R GUI. Do you perhaps know if the startup sequence differs between the two?

Comment: Seems to be an open issue on MacOS with no solution yet: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/9815

Comment: Yes, I see the RStudio bug on MacOS too.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you pointed out the RStudio bug report https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/9815 saying that the `PATH` variable in `.Renviron` isn't picked up in RStudio, but does work in other R front ends.  I can confirm that I see the same behaviour on my system.

You also said that `R_MAX_VSIZE` in your `.Renviron` file also wasn't getting picked up.  I haven't tried that variable, but on my system a non-R environment variable does get picked up from `.Renviron`, and `PATH` does not.

So I think the best workaround for this bug is to make the PATH modification to the system version of the `PATH` before RStudio sees it.  I know how to do that on Windows, but I'm not sure the best way on MacOS.  I tried Googling it, but kept coming up with answers for setting profile files for various shells. Those won't work unless you always start RStudio from a shell, and that's not likely.

I also asked ChatGPT, and it suggested two methods, but both look fairly risky, so I won't repost them here.  One uses `launchctl`, and the other creates an `Environment.plist` file in `/etc`.

An alternate workaround is just to load a function in your `.Rprofile` that makes the change, and run it manually after RStudio starts.